# Javascript Pattern Validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Please can someone assist me with a regular expression to validate a string of this pattern

```
aaa [bbb]
```

I want to an input in the format expressed above. `aaa` & `bbb` can be any combination of one or more words which could also contain special characters. `bbb` must be contained inside square brackets (`[...]`). The full string can have a leading or trailing spaces.

I have tried this:

```
var re=/\w{0,} \[*\w{0,}\]/
```

But it returns false on a test string like:

```
re.test("onc>*!llklk[dd<dfd]")
```

Comment: Yes, but this /\w{0,} \[*\w{0,}\]/.test('aaa [bbb!]'); fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to make it easier to read, you could replace `{0,}` by `*` as it's the same thing.
Next, `\w` would not match some symbols like `>` or `*`, you can use a `.` to match any symbol.
Then, like an other answer is saying, you're expecting a space between the two groups (aaa and [bbb]), so your example won't match.

I think this regex is a good starting point (depending on your other requirements).

```
/.+\[.+\]/
```

[Try it here](http://regex101.com/r/bR0zA1/3)

Comment: Thanks @lechariotdor I tested your solution, it seems okay but fail on this test /.*\[.*\]/.test("[dd<dfd!]"). It returned true instead of false

Comment: Ok, so if you need at least 1 character before the [bbb] group, you should replace the first `*` by a `+`. I edited. If you need at least one character between the `[]` too, you should replace the second `*` too.

Comment: Thanks once again for your effort but latest solution fails this test /.+\[.*\]/.test(" sdsd! sdsd [] "). This should return false

Comment: Hi bro please can you edit your solution to read  /.+\[.+\]/ instead of   /.+\[.*\]/.  /.+\[.+\]/ is the actually the best solution so far

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression explicitly requires a space to be present. We can visualise this with [**Regexper**](http://www.regexper.com/#%2F%5Cw%7B0%2C%7D%20%5C%5B*%5Cw%7B0%2C%7D%5C%5D%2F):

[image: Example]

This returns false on `"onc>*!llklk[dd<dfd]"` because there is no space character.

To fix your problem, either use a test string which has a space character, or change your regular expression to not require this character:

```
var re = /\w{0,}\[*\w{0,}\]/;
```

```js
re.test("aaa [bbb]");
> true

re.test("onc>*!llklk[dd<dfd]");
> true
```

You may want to rethink your regular expression though, because as it stands, a single `"]"` character will pass the test:

```
re.test("]");
> true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\S+\s*\[\S+?\]
```

You can try this if you want to allow special characters as well.

http://regex101.com/r/yA1jY6/3

Comment: Thanks @vks, this is wonderful. It passed series of test cases expect /\S+\s*\[\S+?\]/.test(" sdsd! sdsd [hjhj* sfsd] ") and /\S+\s*\[\S+?\]/.test(" sdsd! sdsd [hjhj*sfsd ] "). Please can you help me that?

Comment: Sorry I mean this is wonderful. It passed series of test cases expect  /\S+\s*[\S+?]/.test(" sdsd! sdsd [] "). Please can you help me that? It passed without bbb and /\S+\s*[\S+?]/.test(" [] ") also passed

Comment: @Paullo This will change the question entirely and the answer.I suggest you post a new question with all requirements.Leave this accepted :)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts @vks but I think lechariotdor have close to what I am looking for